# oledb32.dll cannot improt ado.net while creating setup file

Tags: ado.net

iam creating setup file in ado.net but whenever i build my project it is give me 'oledb32.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll' is under Windows System File Protection error so that's why i download in net and try to import that dll in my project but this file cannot import detected dependencies folder ..oledb32.dll file is important for show  patient details in excel format so can you all expert give me any suggestion or advice

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and couldn't find a concrete answer until now.

I'm using a development box, checking in code via SVN, and running CruiseControl.NET to execute devenv.exe to automatically build the project (I don't use MSBuild because Microsoft hasn't implemented a solution for building Setup projects yet, and I assume this is what you are also using). The setup project would build fine on the dev box but on the build server it kept coming up with that same error.

The MSDN explanation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x97ae5d9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it's not very descriptive, but that's basically what needs to be done. The more concrete answer can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dee631b2-c716-46d8-a693-b31ac8263397/subject-error-building-a-setup-project-using-tfs-build-2008?forum=tfsbuild). Basically you have to **open up VS on your build server and go in and exclude** oledb32.dll (and any other problem files) and voila it finally builds and creates the MSI file! Hope this was helpful for you.